# How to create a basic click event?

Tags: javascript, function, click, dom-events

I've struggled with this for a while and have been following the documentaitons to a 'T' as decribed here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp
But I'm still getting errors. My code:

```
let card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
card.addEventListener('click', cardClicked);

function cardClicked(){

    console.log('clicked');
}
```

I get the following error:

> card.addEventListener is not a function

There must be some basic programming concept I'm completely missing. Can someone help?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection of objects and you need to choose one of them to apply the event listener to. Right now you are trying to add a click listener to a collection.

Comment: Interesting.  I just used querySelector vs etElementsByClassName and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: However, I just realized it only clicks once..... do you know what I would use to make something be clicked multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to subscribe to click event like this:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function cardClicked(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

No need to use any query selectors here.

**UPDATED**: 
If you want to subscribe only specific class elements to event, you may try to do it this way:

```
let cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

 Array.from(cards).forEach(function (element) {
     element.addEventListener('click', function cardClicked() {
        console.log('clicked');
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works but I'm trying to get the cards only to be clicked.  This looks like its effecting the whole document.

Comment: Well, I updated the answer. Please, try the updated solution

Comment: That works great!! Thank you!